# Changing KDE application style from command-line

Tags: command-line, kde, qdbus

I want to change the KDE `Widget Style` via command-line (because my `systemsettings5` crashes while opening and I suspect one of the installed themes so I want to change it via command-line).
I was unable to find anything useful in `~/.config` and some `qdbus` paths.

I know the name of the desired theme , but I don't know the required path in `qdbus`.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: what happens if you try: `LC_ALL=C kcmshell5 style` (.. can list all modules with --list)

Comment: @bac0n Finally I deleted the suspected theme ( ukui ) and the problem got solved. And yes .That now works.But I haven't try that before.